# Buffer Overflow skipping newline

Tags: c, buffer

I was experimenting with stack buffer overflow

```
struct something {
    char A[8];
    unsigned short B;
};

int main(void) {
    struct something st;
    st.B = 1979;
    strcpy(st.A, "excessive");
    printf("%d\n", st.B);
    printf("%s", st.A);
    return 0;
}
```

This worked very well. I got the output as

```
101
excessive
```

But, the string "excessive" has 10 characters including null terminator and therefore it's supposed to overflow even if i change the array to `char A[9]`. But it doesn't overflow in that case and outputs the original value of B. Why is it so? Where is the \0 going?

Comment: How did this work well? You got `101` instead of `1979`.

Comment: "But it doesn't overflow" - Yes it did overflow.  What were you expecting on an overflow?  Something that said "overflow".  In C, if you do not want overflow, don't write outside the legal space to do so.  If code does, you get undefined behavior, not the certainty of an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Allocation of memory follows what is known as *natural alignment*; ie any item in memory is aligned to at least a multiple of its own size.

`unsigned short B` takes a size of 2 bytes (on x86). So it's memory address is aligned to multiples of `2`. When you have `A[8]`, the array consumes an even number of bytes; and `B` starts at the byte just after the last byte of `A`. This is how your string has overflown into the `B`'s memory.

But, `A[9]` takes an odd number of bytes and therefore `B` cannot start at the next byte since it would break the alignment. The compiler will insert a padding byte to ensure that `B` have an address that is a multiple of 2. This extra bytes gives space for the `\0` character to occupy and thus a lucky escape from buffer overflow.

Comment: The OP also wants to know why it works in the case of `char A[8]`.

Comment: "B cannot start at the next byte since it would break the alignment. " It is not that an x86 can not handle unaligned integers, it is that the compiler typically default is to aligned integers for performance reasons.  Some systems will not perform properly with unaligned integers.  x86 is not one of them, it just runs slower.

Answer (score 0):

The `'\0'` is written into the struct member `B`. That also explains why you get `101` in the first `printf` statement. It's working because `strcpy` is not smashing the stack. That means it is not overrunning the memory allocated for the structure variable `st` on the stack. The `C` standard guarantees that the structure members are stored in the order they are declared. However, if necessary, padding is added before each struct member, to ensure correct alignment.

Here, the `strcpy` call

```
strcpy(st.A, "excessive");
```

overruns the structure member array `A` and also writes in the structure member `B`. Luckily, the size of the structure `st` here is just enough for the string literal `"excessive"` to be copied by `strcpy`. On my 32-bit machine, `sizeof st` is `10`. The number of bytes copied by `strcpy` is also `10`. That also explains why the statement

```
printf("%d\n", st.B);
```

prints `101` and not `1979` because its contents has been overwritten by the `strcpy` call. If you try to copy a string longer than `9` characters, or  if you had declared the array `char a[B];` after the `unsigned short B;`, then the call to `strcpy` would attempt illegal memory access causing undefined behaviour and most likely program crash due to segfault.

Also, `'\0'` is called the null character or the null byte, not the newline character which is `'\n'`.